# Preserve type argument in Redux connected component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I have a simple component that takes a type argument on props. When used, it infers the prop type and contextually types a callback param. However, when I wrap the component in `connect()`, it loses the type argument inference and falls back to `unknown`. Example:

```
import React from "react";
import { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux"

type MyCompProps<T> = { 
    value: T; 
    onChange(value: T): void;
}

class MyComp<T> extends Component<MyCompProps<T>> { }

<MyComp value={ 25 } onChange={ val => {/* val will be contextually typed to `number` ✅ */} }/>

const stateToProps = (state: any) => ({ });

const dispatchToProps = { };

const MyContainer = connect(stateToProps, dispatchToProps)(MyComp);

<MyContainer value={ 25 } onChange={ val => {/* val is now `unknown` ❌ */} }/>
```

Is there any way to make `MyContainer` behave like `MyComp`? Either by passing in explicit type args to `connect()` or by writing an assertion on the resulting type?

Answer (score 2):

After a lot failed attempts to make `connect()` behave as I wanted, I found the simplest solution was to just wrap the connected component in another component that re-exposed the type argument and renders the connected component:

```
const ConnectedMyComp = connect(stateToProps, dispatchToProps)(MyComp);

class MyContainer<T> extends Component<MyCompProps<T>> {
    render() {
        return <ConnectedMyComp { ...this.props }/>;
    }
}

<MyContainer value={ 25 } onChange={ val => {/* val is `number`  */} }/>
```

Full example that also deals with the whole dance around own props, state props, and dispatch props: [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4BYAKFEljgG84BhXSAOyTfgF85tcCRdDDJUa0eIzQQ2HDHF788hYjAC0RACYBXAB74qVaWwDO8MyhhIAKhAAKOMCbgBeOAAoLVgFxwUbAE8ASlcAPg8pGTkrTQA1FAAbbSRfLyQAOmNopDjE5IUgikojGTM4TWATMEs0AAtbBwgnVwY4LKQMHIBBDGAZX3cQl3D3Rm4Q7iKqGACwJDgAWQCWcABlGEskRua3ZBhtKDZrWaQAHhm5iEw4NIbHE1Cpygv5pZWwABFK6pg67ec3C8ruVvjV6vZ7k8XotlqwAPIAdzY-1O1nCbkYVDg2LgADc8ik4NZSHAsTiZExav4AOZIdz4pKE6xBXy4iDATRFbiGZ4nGHvf4tN7wpEo-wBcIAMn5rHWm0F0uF4C+VTB-yeaASKBMziVYFR4SQuisbE0zneMk4MFOev+4XoZOxRFNSCggwYjpx2OMZUYDOSABo4BSqWxaUH2p1coyI1EOjEejA+mwFC0YLVKukwJDPV6iPtDh5c16cacKriAPShYvYwqe7mUBslUzwFiyeM5PUtSMwTwbKx3JomIMVVW-cH-ILuPV14qUU5t7KaLv+pAuRgAJgArKmQzS137EmFWhWAFR4o+VOAAA20bAA1mwIEjr3A1HAAEJdD5wU8V1PcFWPKatquqwlwKDABwUAGnARommazCsJaXA2rC4CIsi9wGvanrOporrug6lAlji+YHCmC5xlGXaMOk9Hppm2ZDgoVZFF6DZNvOwoQVBroXoy65wNuu5sJS+5CQyx70GeAlwFe15sNoIAAEauq+74AOJwnCHwAIS-hWvCAaEQA)

Answer (score 0):

There's two different answers here.

The first is that we show a technique for automatically inferring "the type of all props from Redux" in our React-Redux docs ["Usage with TS" usage guide page](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/usage-with-typescript#inferring-the-connected-props-automatically), by using the `ConnectedProps<T>` type and separating the `connect` call into two pieces:

```
import { connect, ConnectedProps } from 'react-redux'

interface RootState {
  isOn: boolean
}

const mapState = (state: RootState) => ({
  isOn: state.isOn,
})

const mapDispatch = {
  toggleOn: () => ({ type: 'TOGGLE_IS_ON' }),
}

const connector = connect(mapState, mapDispatch)

// The inferred type will look like:
// {isOn: boolean, toggleOn: () => void}
type PropsFromRedux = ConnectedProps<typeof connector>
```

That *may* help here, although tbh I really don't know if `connect` will preserve a generic type like that.

That said, the *better* answer is:

**use function components and the hooks API instead of class components and `connect`!**

The hooks API is simpler to use overall, and works *much* better with TypeScript.  In addition, because you're no longer dealing with Higher-Order Components, there's no interference with whatever generic props types you might be using.

Comment: Yeah, the first approach is the same issue, it infers away the type arguments. Thanks for the nudge towards hooks, I am definitely dealing with some anachronistic code here.

Answer (score 0):

This took me a long time to get correct. But I am sharing it here in the hope that it can be of use to somebody.

```js
import React from "react";
import { View } from "react-native";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import * as Redux from "redux";
import { RootAction, RootState } from "../../Reducers";

interface OwnProps<T> {
  options: T[];
  onValueChange?: (value: T, index: number) => void;
  renderItem: (value: T, index: number, isSelected: boolean) => JSX.Element;
  selectedIndex: number;
}

interface StateProps {}

interface DispatchProps {
  dispatch: Redux.Dispatch<RootAction>;
}

type Props<T> = OwnProps<T> & DispatchProps & StateProps;

interface State<T> {
  something: T;
}

export class MyBoxComponent<
  T extends React.ReactNode,
> extends React.PureComponent<Props<T>, State<T>> {
  constructor(props: Props<T>) {
    super(props);
  }

  public render() {
    return <View>{this.props.options}</View>;
  }
}

class MyBox<T extends React.ReactNode> extends React.Component<OwnProps<T>> {
  render() {
    const mapDispatchToProps = (
      dispatch: Redux.Dispatch<Redux.AnyAction>,
    ): DispatchProps => ({
      dispatch,
    });

    const mapStateToProps = (
      state: RootState,
      ownProps: OwnProps<T>,
    ): StateProps => {
      return {};
    };

    const ConnectedComponent = connect(
      mapStateToProps,
      mapDispatchToProps,
    )(MyBoxComponent) as React.ComponentType<OwnProps<T>>;

    return <ConnectedComponent {...this.props} />;
  }
}

export default MyBox;
```

And in the other file:

```js
  type MyType = {
    Description: string;
  } & React.ReactNode;

  const renderItem = React.useCallback(
    (value: MyType, index: number, isSelected: boolean) => {
      return (
        <Text style={isSelected ? styles.fontSelected : styles.font}>
          {value.Description}
        </Text>
      );
    },
    [],
  );

  return (
    <MyBox<MyType>
      options={props.listOfMyType}
      renderItem={renderItem}
      onValueChange={(value, index) => {
        // do something
      }}
      selectedIndex={0}
    />
  );
```